# Why imported value is not callable

Tags: python-3.x

Why is rearrange_name not callable if I imported it?

```
import rearrange_name
import unittest


class TestRearrange(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_basic(self):
        testcase = "Lovelace, Ada"
        expected = "Ada Lovelace"
        self.assertEqual(rearrange_name(testcase), expected)

    def test_empty(self):
        testcase = ""
        expected = ""
        self.assertEqual(rearrange_name(testcase), expected)

    def test_double_name(self):
        testcase = "Hopper, Grace M."
        expected = "Grace M. Hopper"
        self.assertEqual(rearrange_name(testcase), expected)

    def test_one_name(self):
        testcase = "Voltaire"
        expected = "Voltaire"
        self.assertEqual(rearrange_name(testcase), expected)


unittest.main()
```

Comment: You imported a module, not a function. Can you add `rearrange_name.py` to the question?

Comment: Did you by any chance create a module named `rearrange_name` and then included a function in it also named `rearrange_name`?  It sounds like a code smell. Given your `import` statement, you would have to use the function as follows: `rearrange_name.rearrange_name(testcase)`.  Can you see how confusing that might be?  I would suggest naming the module more appropriately.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply and yes I did make a module called rearrange name and I figured out how to fix my problem I changed the import to 'from rearrange_name import rearrange_name' and now it works.